# Java webservice and .net client  Date datatype interpolability issue

Tags: java, .net, web-services, date, types

There is a .net client which calls java web services api - addSchedule(Date startDate, Date endDate). endDate is optional - i.e client can pass endDate= null and all is fine. But the issue is- .Net client cannot assign null to Date variable type.

One more thing we checked, if java web service response passes the null Date value to .net client, this is received as Date.MIN_VALUE by .Net. So we thought what if .Net passes endDate=Date.MIN_VALUE,so java will get the endDate=null. But java is getting Date.MIN_VALUE as valid date.

So we are stuck. Please suggest a good workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to add nillable=true in Java webservice method :-  `addSchedule(Date startDate, @XmlElement(nillable=true) Date endDate)` . With this new wsdl definition, .Net client generates `AddScheule(DateTime, <Nullable>DateTime)`.This is supported by metro 2.2 version jars (jaxb and jaxws.jar). If jre6 has a old version of these jars, download the 2.2 version of these jars and place in the JRE_HOME/lib/endorsed folder. Use the same jre path to build your project.

And when deploying the application on tomcat, copy jaxb and jaxws.jar [2.2 version] in the directory CATALINA_HOME/endorsed. You are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a Nullable DateTime (`Nullable<DateTime>` or `DateTime?`), since this can hold a null value. A normal value type (like DateTime) can't hold null, and will have a default value (in the case of `DateTime` this is `DateTime.MinValue`, but for `int` it is 0)

Comment: When we pass Nullable<DateTime>, It says you cannot pass Nullable<DateTime>, DateTime is expected in addSchedule

Comment: You need to make all the related code use `DateTime?`/`Nullable<DateTime>` or use the `Value` property (note: if you access the `Value` property when it is null, it will throw an exception! You can use the `HasValue` property to check, or compare it to null.

Comment: I don't have much experience with .Net. Just curious what should be the Date dataType on java side in addSchedule, So that on .net side the client wrapper call looks like AddSchdule(DateTime, Nullable<DateTime>)

Comment: If DateTime's are nullable in Java, then you want to use `DateTime?` (which is just short for `Nullable<DateTime>`) wherever you need to use them in .NET. If the values will never actually be null, you can read the `Value` property from the `DateTime?`. Otherwise, you'll need to fix up all the code to correctly handle the `null`s or `Value`s. I's hard to be more specific without knowing exactly what code you're writing, what is being generated, how they're talking to each other, etc.

Comment: In Java, any Object can be assigned 'null', so is `Date` object.Webservice method- `addSchedule(Date startDate, Date endDate)` can be invoked by java client- addSchedule(new Date, null). No issues at all. .Net client,which generates client proxy with Java webservice WSDL results to AddScheule(DateTime, DateTime). But .net client cannot invoke with null value AddSchedule(currentDate, null). Using `Nullable<DateTime>`:  `Nullable<DateTime> endTime = Null; EndPoint.AddSchedule(currentDate, endTime)`.It throws type mismatch error, refer 1 comment above.

Comment: I found a solutions to this. Change the Java api parameter from Date to String - addSchedule(String startDate, String endDate). When no endDate is specified, .net can pass endDate=null in string parameter. And when date is specified, it will pass UTC date in string. Java webservice will parse the string to Date format. Thanks a ton Danny!

Comment: Oh, I see - wasn't sure if your code was generated. I'd be surprised if there wasn't a way to make .NET generate code with `DateTime?` instead. The string method will work, but it's not ideal - be sure you're using *exactly* the same formats (and document it!) :-)